# Increasing integerValue of UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

The is the completion code of the code that animates `squareOne`. When it is clicked it becomes hidden. If the index of the image `squareOne` uses, is the same as `icon` and if `squareOne` is hidden, then the animation repeats. (This is the condition I want the score to increase on). If `squareOne` isn't clicked at all it will still repeat.

```
completion:^(BOOL complete) {
    if (complete) {
        [self squareOneColour];
        [self squareOneMover];
        if (self.squareOne.hidden==YES) {
            if (a==b) {
                [self squareOneColour];
                [self squareOneMover];
                //I want the score to increase here
            } else if (a!=b) {
                [self squareOneColour];
                [self squareOneMover];
                NSLog(@"square one isn't supposed to be pressed");
}}}}];} //Just to make more compact
```

When I try doing this I always create dozens of `NSString` and `NSUInteger` variable and I think my way is inefficient, and it doesn't work... Can anyone help me get the `integerValue` of the textfield `score` to increase every time `squareOne` is pressed and matches the image on `icon`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using:

```
myTextField.text = @(_myTextField.text.integerValue + 1).stringValue;
```

What we're doing is:

- Get the integerValue from the text field and add one
- Set it back as the value on the text field's text peroperty, by boxing it as an NSNumber (using '@') and then call the stringValue method on it.

Regarding code formatting:

- I recommend not to use trailing comments, eg `foo += 5 //Add foo-tax`. The rationale is that developers can waste time getting trailing comments to line up and be formatted nicely. Its a common 'lint' check in code quality tools.
- Don't pack up all of your braces into one line. It's usually best to stick to formatting conventions.

Comment: `integerValue` is a property of `NSString` and `stringValue` is a property of `NSNumber`, so your "technically" note is unnecessary.  Apple changed a boat-load of methods like these into properties with iOS 8.

Comment: @nhgrif "Technically dot notation is only for properties, but it can look nice for simple methods (ones that would be "computed properties" in Swift)." . . ah, you're right.